# nginx, php-fcgi, VBulletin, Wordpress & Node.js

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress, node.js, vbulletin

CompassionPit.com is a Node.js app.  The CompassionPit blog is WordPress and the CompassionPit forum is VBulletin.  Everything was working fine and dandy until I installed the VBseo plugin for VBulletin, which wants me to add these lines to my nginx configuration:

```
    location /forum/ {
            rewrite ^/forum/((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ /forum/vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 last;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/vbseo.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /forum/(.*\.php)$ {
            rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /forum/vbseo.php last;
    }
    location /forum/vbseo/(includes|resources/html|resources/xml)/ {
            allow      127.0.0.1;
            deny      all;
    }
```

Here's the updated configuration file, including the 3 new blocks, which I placed at the bottom of the file.

```
server {
    listen       80;                # your server's public IP address
    server_name  www.compassionpit.com;
    index        index.php index.html;

    location ~ ^/$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        break;
    }

    location @blogphp {
        internal;
        root /opt/blog;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8080;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/(forum|blog)/($|.*\.php) {
        root /opt/;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8080;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/(blog|forum) {
        root /opt/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blogphp;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/(forum|blog|vbulletin)/ {
       root /opt/;
       break;
    }

    location @backend {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        break;
    }

    location ~ / {
        root /opt/chat/static/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
        break;
    }




    location /forum/ {
            rewrite ^/forum/((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ /forum/vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 last;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/vbseo.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /forum/(.*\.php)$ {
            rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /forum/vbseo.php last;
    }
    location /forum/vbseo/(includes|resources/html|resources/xml)/ {
            allow      127.0.0.1;
            deny      all;
    }

}
```

You see, http://www.compassionpit.com/forum/general-discussion/ is getting served by WordPress.

Any suggestions for how I can condense the nginx file to integrate the VBSEO changes?

Thank you!

--Zachary

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably mistaken, but it would seem removing the handlers for "forum" in the "(forum/blog)" to just read blog (removing the or logic) would fix this.  I'm probably wrong, though, I haven't used any of the products mentioned. Try it though, let us know :)

Comment: In both cases, of course.

Comment: I tried that, it did not yield the desired behavior.  I think the file just needs to be totally refactored -- it's a mess.

Comment: I actually found out, just now (since I received the message notification) that there was more to the config than I was able to see on my phone :X  Seems I wasn't being shown a scroll bar, when I needed to be D:  Sorry if I've wasted any time ;)